# Displaying history of users employment - MySQL , CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to create an SQL query that gets the records from multiple tables, showing a users employment history.

I'm getting an error in my join statement that says there's an error with the alias of a table.

> Error Number: 1066
>
> Not unique table/alias: 'role'

```
$this->db->select('*');
    $this->db-> from ('project_roles AS role' , 'project_tasks AS task', 'project AS proj');
    $this->db-> join ('employee_assignment AS ea', 'role.roleID = ea.roleID');
    $this->db-> join ('role', 'task.taskID = role.taskID ');
    $this->db-> join ('task', 'proj.projectID = task.projectID');
    $this->db-> where('ea.accountID', $accountID);
```

If anyone could identify what I'm doing wrong, that would be great. All of the tables have the fields being used in this query. I just don't know why it isn't identifying 'role'... unless of course that's just the first error it has found so far.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting all the tables in the from put them in the joins

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db-> from ( 'project AS proj');
$this->db-> join ('project_tasks AS task', 'proj.projectID = task.projectID');
$this->db-> join ('project_roles AS role', 'task.taskID = role.taskID ');
$this->db-> join ('employee_assignment AS ea', 'role.roleID = ea.roleID');
$this->db-> where('ea.accountID', $accountID);
```